# Term for perishable goods that are non-divisible with a set redemption date (concert tickets vs. Milk)

Tags: commodities, product-differentiation

What is the terminology to distinguish goods like milk and concert tickets.

Both are perishable.

If we were to say milk expired on the last day of the month, and a concert will occur on the last day of the month.

Milk can be partially redeemed or used at any point over the course of the month.

Concert tickets are non-divisible and May only be redeemed at a specific time and location.

What terms economic terms are used to specify “divisibility” and “fixed-date redemption”

Comment: I think of tickets as a service. The concert is a service provided once. No further utilization once the service is offered